# ContentLength not set after write

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to send data to a server with this function :

```
public static async Task<Byte[]> sendData(Byte[] bt)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
            myWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            myWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            myWebRequest.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
            using (var requestStream = (Stream)(await Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(myWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream, myWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream, myWebRequest)))
            {
                requestStream.Write(bt, 0, bt.Length);
            }

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(myWebRequest.BeginGetResponse, myWebRequest.EndGetResponse, myWebRequest)))
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    bt = new byte[responseStream.Length];
                    responseStream.Read(bt, 0, bt.Length);
                    return bt;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

I get a response from the server saying that no data was sent (ContentLength == 0). Indeed, if I look at myWebRequest.ContentLength after writing in the stream request, `_ContentLength` is set to 0 and `ContentLength`is set to -1.

Did I miss something ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Does your code explicitly set content-length to be 0, or does the server falsely assume that content-length must be set?

Comment: why do you gave the windows phone tags?

Comment: @CodeCaster : I use only this code. ContentLength is never set. Even if try to set it via the HeaderCollection, problem remain the same.

Comment: @UtsavDawn : Because it's a windows phone project.

Comment: That was not my question. No content-length header does not mean there's no content.

Comment: @CodeCaster : To know if there is a content on the server, I look at Request.InputStream.Length. If it's 0, I assume there is no content. Is it wrong ? At first, I was looking at Request.ContentLength but as it was always 0...

Comment: @CodeCaster : As it is a 269 bytes xml, I assume it is not send in chunks. Do you have a line of code to show me how to read the request body ?